# Windows 10 - Can't move window to other virtual desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-desktop

Usually I was able to move a window to another virtual desktop by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and then moving the window to the target virtual desktop.

But now if I press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> then nothing happens anymore. I only notice that the "active apps" symbol in the task bar is changing.

[image]

I tried it on another computer and there it still works.

The windows key is not locked on my keyboard.

Comment: Did it work when you clicked the task-view icon and then dragged the desired window?

Comment: Where is the "Task View" button? How does it look

Comment: The one which you have circled is the task view button

Comment: @Valay_17, nothing happens if I click on this button. It just animates.

Comment: Seems like the feature is not working, it is not the problem of your keyboard for sure.

Comment: Try restoring windows or trying out a recovery point to the last time it was correctly working

Comment: Try this combination of keys and let me know if you move from 1 virtual desktop to the other. Open any application and then press Win+Ctrl+D and then open any application(other than the first one), don’t minimize any of the applications and then press Win+Ctrl+ left/right arrow key. If you are able to see a sliding motion happening or you see that you are switching from one application to the other, than you are able to create new virtual desktops and switch between them, if nothing happens, then you need to consult Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Today it works again after I started the computer. If you ever face this problem, then just restart your system.

Answer (score -1):

How to move windows between virtual desktops in Windows 10
Click the Task View button in your taskbar.
Click and hold the window you want to move.
Drag and release the window on an alternate desktop.

Comment: Where is the "Task View" button? How does it look

Comment: This answer is confusing.  You should clarify it by editing it